# show data from SQLite to Custom ListView in android studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I want to show my data from sqlite to Custom ListView (java , Android studio , sqlite ).
But it's force stop.

picture from my Main Activity:
[image: first image]

picture from my Database class:
[image: second image]

Please Help me!!!!
(my English is not good sorry but can i understand your words)

Comment: your images are not attached.

Comment: add your exception stack trace

Comment: Please don't include images of your code. Copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: We don't need **screenshots**. We need **code**.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create a custom adapter for your listview and populate that  adapter with listview and your code should be like this
and to get the data from database create a method in database class name getdata() take it in a form of cursor

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASENAME = "DATABASENAME2";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
public static final String DEVICE = "device"; //your coloumn
public static final String ADDRESS = "address";//your coloumn
public static final String Date = "Date"; //your coloumn
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+DEVICE+" TEXT,"+ADDRESS+" TEXT,"+Date+"TEXT);";


public UserDbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASENAME,null,DB_VERSION);


}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

}

public List<Datalist> getdata()
{
 List<Datalist> result = new ArrayList<>();
 Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table_name,null";);
 while (c.moveToNext()) {
result.add(
                new Datalist(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("YOUR COLOUMN")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("YOUR COLOUMN")),
                        date

                )
        );
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

and populate your database with listview

this will be in your button click that button which retrive the data

```
List<Datalist> itemFromDatabase = getItemFromDatabase();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0,  itemFromDatabase);
listOfDatabaseObject.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but what is the DataList? a class? whitch class?

Comment: datalist is the dataprovider which provide data to custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DataBaseHelper  myDbHelper;
List<String>    stringList;
ListView listView;
List<Mivejat> mivejatList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }

    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    mivejatList = myDbHelper.MiveName();

    for (int i = 0 ; 0 < mivejatList.size() ; i++) {
        stringList.add(mivejatList.get(i).name);
    }
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMive);

    mainListViewClass mainListViewClass = new mainListViewClass(MainActivity.this , stringList);
    listView.setAdapter(mainListViewClass);
    mainListViewClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

    myDbHelper.close();
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DataBaseHelper  myDbHelper;
List<String>    stringList;
ListView listView;
List<Mivejat> mivejatList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }

    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    mivejatList = myDbHelper.MiveName();

    for (int i = 0 ; 0 < mivejatList.size() ; i++) {
        stringList.add(mivejatList.get(i).name);
    }
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMive);

    mainListViewClass mainListViewClass = new mainListViewClass(MainActivity.this , stringList);
    listView.setAdapter(mainListViewClass);
    mainListViewClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

    myDbHelper.close();
}
```

}

DataBaseHelper.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/mivejat.rezaahmadpour.ir.mivejat/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "KhavasMiveha.db";
public static final int DB_VERS = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
private static String TAG = "KhavasMiveha.db";

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERS);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates an empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 */
public boolean createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        Log.d(TAG, "database already exist");

        //Running this method causes SQLite class checking for if New DB Version Exists and runs upgrade method
        getReadableDatabase();
        close();

        return true;
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transferring bytestream.
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.d(TAG, "UPGRADING Database...");
    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }

}

public List<Mivejat> MiveName() {
    String query = "SELECT Name FROM tbl_mive";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    List<Mivejat> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Mivejat m;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        m = new Mivejat();
        m.name = cursor.getString(0);
        result.add(m);
    }
    return result;
}
```